# Как запустить phpadmin на xampp Ubuntu 20?

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

Установил XAMPP, страницы сайта отображаются, дошло дело и до БД. Как с внешнего компьютера получить http-доступ к phpadmin, который установлен вне директории htdoc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое вот [решение](http://www.sintesisdigital.com.mx/dashboard/docs/access-phpmyadmin-remotely.html) есть:

1. Необходимо отредактировать файл конфигурации по пути `apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`
2. Внутри файла найти блок:

   ```
    <Directory "/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
      AllowOverride AuthConfig
      Require local
      …
   ```

   Заменить **Require local** на **Require all granted**:

   ```
    <Directory "/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
      AllowOverride AuthConfig
      Require all granted
      …
   ```
3. Сохранить файл и перезапустить **Apache server** через контрольную панель XAMPP.

---

Но вообще XAMPP придумали для исключительно локальной разработки, поэтому все внешние коммуникации там отключены по дефолту, для безопасности и удобства.

Если необходима связка нескольких машин, или смотреть во внешнюю сеть, лучше не насиловать XAMPP, а поставить все компоненты отдельно. Apache или Nginx, БД и т.д. Чтобы сильно не заморачиваться с iptables можно использовать Shorewall.

Comment: Внес изменения, но как получить доступ извне, ведь я обращаюсь к серверу по адресу. Сделал просто - перенес папку phpmyadmin внутрь htdoc и все заработало ip_addr/phpmyadmin. У меня сервер без доступа к репам, посчитал что быстрее будет поставить xampp, это для внутренних пользователей, ну там 2-3 человека, включая меня, так что безопасность на втором месте.